# NodeJS Child Node Process

Tags: node.js, mongoose, child-process

I am trying to fork a child process that will go out a load data from a 3rd party api into a mongodb instance.  When I try to connect to mongodb inside the child process I get Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH.  This is a local instance and I can connect in the parent process.  Is this a context issue inside the child process?

Comment: This looks like an issue with mongoose.  I do not get an error using the mongo native.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

You should make you code decoupling, so you can test the child_process standalone, and trace your error.

To cache the error of child process, you can add below code in your entry js of your child process

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```